# Allow two subnets to talk to each other over a wireless bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have two subnets connected over a wireless bridge and I'm trying to figure out how to get them to talk to each other.

#### Subnet 1

- Router:      Netgear wireless
- Router IP:   192.168.1.1
- DHCP range:  192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254
- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- Internet:    Connected directly to cable modem

#### Subnet 2

- Router:      Linksys running dd-wrt
- Router IP:   192.168.2.1
- DHCP range:  192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.254
- Internet:    Connected to the Netgear router via a wireless bridge
- WAN IP:      192.168.1.10

When I'm on Subnet 1, I can't connect to anything on Subnet 2 (even the wireless bridge IP of 192.168.1.10).

When I'm on Subnet 2, I can connect to everything on 192.168.2.* as well as the Subnet 1 router on 192.168.1.1. But I *can't* connect to any other machines on Subnet 1.

The physical limitations of my house make the wireless bridge a requirement. I don't think making a wired connection between the two subnets is an option.

How can I set things up so machines on both subnets can communicate with each other and still get to the Internet?

Comment: You could set the subnet mask on all machines to

  255.255.224.0
This way your host IP address range is 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.31.254, which includes both subnets you mention.

Comment: Wired or wireless is just a medium, the "network" it carriers is mostly not relevant to the actual medium. If this is a wireless bridge, why is the second router providing DHCP and not just transparently passing the 192.168.1.0/24 network through? That would make this so much simpler, router one provides DHCP to everything, and router 2 just acts a bridge passing the wireless network to the wired ports. Sounds to me like this is misconfigured since this is a SOHO environment.

Comment: I tried changing the subnet at one point and it still wasn't working. Would I have to do anything in terms of setting the Gateway on Subnet 2 for that to work?

Comment: I'll take a look and see about disabling the secondary DHCP and just making it all one big 192.168.1.0 network.

Comment: Your router 2 is misconfigured, it should not be doing any router or DHCP functions, everything should be handled by router 1. Router 2 should be just a pass-though of the network. Everything should be one 192.168.1.0/24 subnet with a gateway of 192.168.1.1

Comment: I think this is the information you are looking for: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is not a wireless bridge, just a way of using the wireless medium to carry a network connection to another router, the second "router" should be setup as a bridge to pass-thru all network traffic, making this all one subnet with one router handling all DHCP and routing functions for the entire LAN. This is called a Client-Bridge configuration and is a common DD-WRT application.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged